# utilizar shadowbox.js con href variable el cual se carga desde sql y json

Tags: javascript, html, sql, json

Hola amigos espero y puedan ayudarme lo que pasa es que intento mostrar un sahdowbox desde codigo javascript y json y hago una conexion sql a travez de un webmethod.

La manera en que estoy intentando mostrar el shadowbox es asi:

```
<br>
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pagina.aspx/webmethod",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var objeto = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ?
<br>
<a id="a1" rel="shadowbox;width=518;height=350;" title="' + objeto[i].titulo + '"' + ' href= ' + '"' + objeto[i].liga + '"' + '><div>Ver</div></a>
<br>
<br>
```

Gracias de antemano saludos.

Comment: Buenas tardes. Tu pregunta es un poco vaga. Si nos das más detalles, podemos ayudarte mejor. Lee el artículo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para saber como formular una pregunta de forma adecuada

Comment: si me trae los valores correctos desde sql, pero cuando le doy click a la liga no se ejecuta el shadowbox, se abre toda la pagina